# Javascript error message for rock, paper, scissors game

Tags: javascript

Please i need help with the code below.
I have been getting this error message **SyntaxError: expected expression, got keyword 'if'** and I think I'm doing the right thing.

```js
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
var computerChoice = Math.random();
`enter code here`
if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
  computerChoice = "rock";
} else if (computerChoice <= 0.67) {
  computerChoice = "paper";
} else {
  computerChoice = "scissors";
}
console.log("Computer: " + computerChoice);
var compare = function(choice1, choice2)
if (choice1 === choice2) {
  return "The result is a tie!";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Content of functions in Javascript goes inside braces. So your current code

```
var compare = function(choice1, choice2)
if (choice1 === choice2) {
  return "The result is a tie!";
}
```

will become

```
var compare = function(choice1, choice2)
{
    if (choice1 === choice2) {
      return "The result is a tie!";
    }
}
```